# Automated scripting of database with data

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 it is possible to script data from SQL Server Management Studio.

I would like to make a job, that scripts everything in my database (tables, stored procedures etc) to one file and all data in some tables to another.

Is it possible - and what is the easiest way to do it?

The reason why I want this is so I can put my development databases under source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ScriptDb from Elsasoft](http://www.elsasoft.org/tools.htm) does this. It is an open source commandline app from Elsasoft.

Comment: Updated version is over at codeplex now: http://scriptdb.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the database, and select Tasks, then Generate Script.  In the wizard on the options page, change Script Data from false to true.

Comment: That is not what I asked. I want to automate it, so I can run it in a scheduler that does what you just described.

Comment: There's no native way to script out the database or the data.  I'm not sure if the their party tools can be scheduled to do this either.